# My mind is baffled by this simple equation in C#

Tags: c#

I've got a problem. I'm attempting to make a Farenheit to Celcius calculator, and when I do the fraction part of math, it kinda doesn't work. It's either 0 or 1.

```
private void toCelcius_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double F = double.Parse(temperatureBox.Text);
    double fm32 = F - 32;
    double fraction = (9 / 5);
    double newTemp = fraction*fm32;

    temperatureLabel.Text = newTemp.ToString();
}
```

I've been using 100 as my test number, and everytime I send 100 to the textbox, it returns 68. It should be somewhere around 30ish.

Currently the program only senses the fraction as a 1. I tried using decimal instead of using double, but that breaks the newTemp problem. I tried using float, but got same results as a double. I have no freaking idea whats going on but it's very frustrating.

If anyone knows how to fix this, I'd be very thankful.

EDIT: *Facepalm* it's been such a long time since I've used doubles, forgot I needed to have the .0 after each number.

Comment: Isn't the formula F - 32 (5/9)?

Comment: yea.. I noticed that after I submitted it, but either way, it didn't give the right answer

Answer (score 5):

You should put `double` for your number:

```
private void toCelcius_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double F = double.Parse(temperatureBox.Text);
    double fm32 = F - 32;
    double fraction = ((double)9 / 5);
    double newTemp = fraction*fm32;

    temperatureLabel.Text = newTemp.ToString();
}
```

Otherwise, `9` will be read as `int` since this is the base C# literal for number (without comma or any other suffix like `D`). That is why you always get fraction as `1` because: `9/5 = 1.8` will be read as `1` in `int`

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
double fraction = (9D / 5); //the shortest (credit for Coxy)
```

Or, for more readability:

```
double fraction = (9.0 / 5); //like what we have in math (as pointed out by Michael Burr)
```

Comment: Oh.. I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: yea I feel dumb, that worked haha thank you :)

Comment: `9D` may be more readable than `(double)9`.

Comment: @Coxy yes, that would have been the shortest answer. :) I merely show the necessity of casting without considering the shortest way (edited)

Comment: Wouldn't `9.0` be even more readable?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively use;

```
Double fraction = 9.0 / 5.0;
```

Comment: yea, I forgot I had to use the .0's after each number for a double.. lol - thanks

Comment: @JohnOlivas actually for you case, you only need to put `.0` for any **one** of the numbers, the other will be automatically promoted for operation. But writing in both for readability is fine too. ;)